# Bash Script to Replace a word followed by colon followed by a space and then a number

Tags: bash, shell

i want to find the revision number in a file- there will be an input of a new revision number from a user and this new one will replace the old one.
example:

```
revision: 56
```

should be replaced with 67 if the users input is 67, like this;

```
revision: 67
```

I want a bash script which would find and replace the old number with the new one. The value for the new revision number will be stored in the variable revision_number.

So far this is what i got:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Insert the new revision number: “

read revision_number

sed -e  ^revision: \d+$/^revision: $revision_number$  *.txt
```

Comment: What is your script doing that you aren't happy with?

Comment: with that script i am getting this response "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'"

Comment: A regexp in sed needs to be introduced by a slash. Plus: You forgot to quote your sed expression, so sed sees only `^revision:` as an argument to `-e`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
sed "s/^revision:.*/revision: ${input}/" file
```

Comment: this one worked; sed -i "s/^revision:.*/revision: ${revision_number}/" ./*.txt

Comment: Plus 1 for being 2 minutes faster than me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using sed

To change the files in place with sed, use:

```
sed -i -E "s/^revision: [[:digit:]]+$/revision: $revision_number/"  *.txt
```

**Notes:**

1. sed supports POSIX regular expressions.  `\d` is not POSIX.  `[[:digit:]]` is POSIX and is superior to `[0-9]` because it is unicode safe.
2. `+` is not supported in POSIX's basic regular expressions.  Use `-E` to get extended regular expressions.
3. `-i` tells sed to change the files in place.
4. Note that sed treats `$revision_number` not as data but as part of the command.  **This is dangerous.**  Malicious values of `$revision_number` could cause files to be deleted or overwritten.
5. **Compatibility**:  The above works for modern GNU sed.  For very old GNU sed, replace `-E` with `-r`:

   ```
   sed -i -r "s/^revision: [[:digit:]]+$/revision: $revision_number/"  *.txt
   ```

   For BSD/OSX sed, replace `-i` with `-i ''`:

   ```
   sed -i '' -E "s/^revision: [[:digit:]]+$/revision: $revision_number/"  *.txt
   ```

#### Using GNU awk

To change the files in-place using GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace -v r="$revision_number" '{sub(/^revision: [[:digit:]]+/, "revision: " r)} 1' *.txt
```

**Notes:**

1. BSD/OSX awk does not support `-i inplace`.
2. Because awk treats `$revision_number` as data **not** code, this is much safer to use than the sed approach.

Comment: Plus one for the very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

perl

```
perl -i -spe 's/^revision:\s+\K\d+/$revno/g' -- -revno="$revision_number" *.txt
```

Comment: plus one for the hat! :)